# Looking for the name of a specific jQuery Autocomplete Control

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

At this website http://8tracks.com/tristad/fine-life-we-are-livin in the top-right corner there is an input search box. When you start to type there, it shows a dropdown autocomplete menu of items. Does anybody know what is the name of that UI Control? Or a library which provides such a control? I want to make a similar control but do not know where I can take it.

Comment: Like jQuery UI Autocomplete?

Comment: Just try Googling "jQuery autocomplete" and you'll get several libraries - you already seemed to know the name of the control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are few libraries that you can use for auto complete:

1. [jquery autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).
2. http://fromvega.com/wordpress/2007/05/05/auto-complete-field-with-jquery-json-php/
3. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-use-the-jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget/
4. http://www.jquery4u.com/ajax/10-ajaxjquery-autocomplete-tutorial-examples/

Comment: Anyone know what happened to fromvega site ?  It seems to be dissapeared

Answer (score 1):

JQuery UI has a feature like this to provide autocontrol. Please check the link, if it would work for you. http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they are using the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) (not jQuery UI), [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/), and [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) libraries on their site. I don't think these libs have any built-in autocomplete input widgets/functionality, but there are certainly third-party ones, such as [this one](http://fatiherikli.github.io/backbone-autocomplete/) using Backbone. A Google search should turn some up. They have likely chosen a third-party plugin/utility, or wrote one themselves.

Alternatively, you can use the [Autocomplete widget](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) in the [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) library, which is probably the fastest way for you to throw some autocomplete input functionality onto a page.